# PHP e-mail not getting sent

Tags: php, macos, email

I am trying to execute following simple `PHP` program to send e-mail:

```
<?php
  $to = "alokur@test.com";
  mail($to, "subject test", "hello from php", "From: alokur@test.com");
?>
```

But, when executed from my Mac terminal, I am getting following warning and email is not being sent:

```
postdrop: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/91512.35994: Permission denied
```

Any clues? Thanks